# Print A Div Containing Dynamic Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I print a `div` in `javascript` by using the following code:

```
 $('body').on('click','button#printreceipt',function(){
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        var divContents = $("#appendReceiptHere").html();
        printWindow.document.write(divContents);
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.document.close();

    });
```

The `div` contains dynamically generated images, like

```
<img src="/mysite/generate_test_image.php" />
```

The div is correctly shown and the dynamic image as well. But when I try to print the div, the image is not shown, it disappears.

Any hint?

Comment: Shouldn't you issue `print` command before closing `document`?

Comment: nothing changes...:)

Comment: the div exists on the current page, not in the new window you open to print. and `print()` just opens the print dialog.

Comment: Try waiting for the image to load before issuing the print command

Comment: @WhiteHat: but i put the content of the div into the window I will open...

Comment: if you can make an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try waiting for images loading and then print.

So, instead to print in your function try to print on window `onload` event inside the pop up window like:

```
$('body').on('click','button#printreceipt',function(){
   var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
   var divContents = $("#appendReceiptHere").html() +
                        "<script>" +
                        "window.onload = function() {" +
                        "     window.print();" +
                        "};" +
                        "<" + "/script>";
   printWindow.document.write(divContents);
   printWindow.document.close();
});
```